# python socket OSError: [WinError 10038] an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to python, and I came across this code, but It come up with an error (the title)

I run `py server_chat.py (ip) 21567`
and `py client.py (ip) 21567`
This is my code in chat_server.py

```
import socket
import select
from _thread import *
import sys


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Correct usage: script, IP address, port number")
    exit()
IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
Port = int(sys.argv[2])
server.bind((IP_address, Port)) 
server.listen(100)
list_of_clients=[]

def clientthread(conn, addr):
    conn.send("Welcome to this chatroom!")
    while True:
            try:     
                message = conn.recv(2048)    
                if message:
                    print("<" + addr[0] + "> " + message)
                    message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message
                    broadcast(message_to_send,conn)
                else:
                    remove(conn)
            except:
                continue

def broadcast(message,connection):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients!=connection:
            try:
                clients.send(message)
            except:
                clients.close()
                remove(clients)

def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)

while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    list_of_clients.append(conn)
    print(addr[0] + " connected")
    start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,addr))

conn.close()
server.close()
```

And I get this error for chat_server.py (it says connected, but then gives an error):

```
(ip) connected!
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function clientthread at 0x0000019F8B0AE040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 26, in clientthread
    conn.send("Welcome to this chatroom!")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This is my code in client.py

```
    import socket
    import select
    import sys
    
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print ("Correct usage: script, IP address, port number")
        exit()
    IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
    Port = int(sys.argv[2])
    server.connect((IP_address, Port))
    
    while True:
    
        sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
    
        read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
    
        for socks in read_sockets:
            if socks == server:
                message = socks.recv(2048)
                print (message)
            else:
                message = sys.stdin.readline()
                server.send(message)
                sys.stdout.write("<You>")
                sys.stdout.write(message)
                sys.stdout.flush()
    server.close()
```

And I get this error for client.py

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 27, in <module>
    read_sockets,write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket is not a socket
```

Please help, I don't know what to do.

Comment: `sys.stdin` is not a socket on Windows. That code will probably not work on Windows.

Comment: @AKX Perhaps use `sys.stdin.fileno()`

Comment: @PeterWood Sockets and files aren't the same thing on Windows like they are on Unix – you can't use the socket family Win32 API functions on file handles.